# Ruby- Change the layout on button release without changing the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to have my Flash animation in fullscreen when I press a html button under the animation. I have a ../views/layout/viewer.rhtml (this one loads all menus). I have ./views/layout/fullscreen.rhtml (this one do not have menus, it has only 100% width and 100% height and the flash object). I would like to avoid Javascript method.

I have a show_controller:

```
    layout "viewer"

 def index
    h = Histoire.find_by_label(params[:story_name])
    # Checks if current_user has a subscription which allows the story whose ID is passed by param to be seen
    if h.price != 0 && (current_user.nil? || current_user.abonnement.histoires.delete_if{|histoire| histoire.label != params[:story_name]}.length == 0)
      flash[:notice] = "Sorry, your subscription doesn't allow you to access this story, please contact sales service"
      redirect_to index_url
    else

      @histoire = Histoire.find_by_label(params[:story_name])
      render :action => :show
    end
  end
```

I have a flash object:

My flash Animation need to have a fixed URL to run: /show/Story_Name, the current layout is viewer. When I press FullScreen button, I'd like Ruby to change the layout from "viewer" to "fullscreen".

Is there a way to change the layout from viewer to fullscreen when a button is pressed?

I'm beginner in this matter. Thanks a lot to the one who will help me.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby code is executed on the server side, it won't do anything unless you reload the page to make another call to your controller, for example using a "layout_mode" parameter you may use in your view template.

I would use an unobtrusive javascript approach :

- use a link to reload the page and change the layout_mode to fullscreen. This behavior allows user with Javascript disabled to access he fullscreen switch feature
- use jQuery to modify this link so it changes the layout on click without reloading the page for the regular users

**Side note** : I would advice you to avoid naming your model objects in French, as Rails is strongly convention-oriented and makes an extensive use of english-inflections : Rails will consider stories as a collection and story as an individual member. It would work with "gourou" and "joujou" but won't with "hibou", "caillou", "chou"... ;)

Comment: Better late than never thanks a lot for your answer and your advices about inflections.